# getting 2 dots (point) in calculator program using angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am doing an **angular js calculator** and i am unable to get the solution to include only one dot/point for decimal number calculation. When you click on "." button in calculator you get 2 dots which is not a valid decimal operation. 
Below is the code i tried for verifying decimal point. Also if anybody could be give an idea of how to exactly make ac button/function to work.

```
if(otpt.indexOf('.') == -1) {
    $scope.zeroflag = false;        
} else {
    $scope.zeroflag = true;
}
```

I tried a lot but not able to find solution.

Here is my full calculator program on codepen: [AngularJS calculator](https://codepen.io/abhilashn/pen/mMwZGQ)

```js
var calc = angular.module('calc', []);
 var currentval;
 calc.controller('calcCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.output = 0;
  
  $scope.history = "";
  var operator = "";
   // Used to evaluate whether to start a new number
    // in the display and when to concatenate
    $scope.newNumber = true;
  
  // Holds the pending operation so calculate knows
    // what to do
   $scope.pendingOperation = null;
  
  // Bound to the view to display a token indicating
    // the current operation
    $scope.operationToken = "";
  
  // Holds the running total as numbers are added/subtracted
  $scope.runningTotal = null;
  
  // Holds the number value of the string in the display output
  $scope.pendingValue = null;
   
  // Tells calculate what to do when the equals buttons is clicked repeatedly
  $scope.lastOperation = null;
  
  // Constants
    var ADD = "adding";
    var SUBTRACT = "subtracting";
    var MULTIPLY = "multiplying";
    var DIVIDE = "dividing";
    var ADD_TOKEN = "+";
    var SUBTRACT_TOKEN = "-";
    var MULTIPLY_TOKEN = "*";
    var DIVIDE_TOKEN = "/";
    
    
    /* Runs every time a number button is clicked.
  * Updates the output display and sets 
  * newNumber flag
  */
  $scope.updateOutput = function(btn) {
    if($scope.output == "0" || $scope.newNumber) {
 
   $scope.output = btn;
   //$scope.history = String(btn);
      $scope.newNumber = false;
    } else {
  var otpt = String( $scope.output);
  console.log(otpt.indexOf('.'));
  if(otpt.indexOf('.') == -1) {
    $scope.zeroflag = false;   
  } else {
   $scope.zeroflag = true;
  }
  $scope.output += String(btn);
    }
    $scope.pendingValue = toNumber($scope.output);
 $scope.history += String(btn);
 console.log($scope.pendingValue);
  };
  
  /* Converts a string to a number so we can
  * perform calculations. Simply multiplies
  * by one to do so
  */
  toNumber = function(numberString) {
    var result = 0;
    if(numberString) {
      result = numberString*1;
    }
    return result;
  };
  
  /* 
  * Updates the display output and resets the
  * newNumber flag.
  */
  setOutput = function(outputString) {
    $scope.output = outputString;
    $scope.newNumber = true;
  };
  
  
  /* 
  * Sets the operation token to let the user know
  * what the pendingOperation is
  */
  setOperationToken = function(operation) {
    if(operation == ADD) {
      $scope.operationToken = ADD_TOKEN;
    } 
 else if (operation == MULTIPLY) {
      $scope.operationToken = MULTIPLY_TOKEN;
    } else if (operation == SUBTRACT) {
      $scope.operationToken = SUBTRACT_TOKEN;
    } else if(operation == DIVIDE) {
   $scope.operationToken = DIVIDE_TOKEN;
 } else {
      $scope.operationToken = "";
    }
  $scope.history += $scope.operationToken;
  };  
  
  $scope.clear = function() {
   $scope.runningTotal = null;
   $scope.pendingValue = null;
   $scope.pendingOperation = null;
   setOutput("0");
   $scope.history = "";
   $scope.zeroflag = false;
  }
  
  $scope.ac = function() {
   $scope.pendingValue = null;
   
   setOutput("0");
   $scope.zeroflag = false;
  }
  
  
   /*
  * Runs every time the add button is clicked.
  * If a number has been entered before the add
  * button was clicked we set the number as a pendingValue,
  * set ADD as a pendingOperation, and set the token. 
  * If no number was entered but an existing calculated
  * number is in the output display we add the last added
  * value on to the total again.
  */
  $scope.add = function() {
   $scope.zeroflag = false;
    if($scope.pendingValue) { 
 if($scope.runningTotal && ($scope.pendingOperation == DIVIDE)) {
  $scope.runningTotal /= $scope.pendingValue;
 } else
   if($scope.runningTotal && ($scope.pendingOperation == MULTIPLY) ) {
        $scope.runningTotal *= $scope.pendingValue;
      } else
      if($scope.runningTotal && $scope.pendingOperation == ADD ) {
        $scope.runningTotal += $scope.pendingValue;
      } else if($scope.runningTotal && $scope.pendingOperation == SUBTRACT ) {
        $scope.runningTotal -= $scope.pendingValue;
      }
      else {
        $scope.runningTotal = $scope.pendingValue;
      }
    } 
    setOperationToken(ADD);
    setOutput(String($scope.runningTotal));
    $scope.pendingOperation = ADD;
    $scope.newNumber = true;
    $scope.pendingValue = null;
  };
  
  /*
  * Runs every time the subtract button is clicked.
  * If a number has been entered before the subtract
  * button was clicked we set the number as a pendingValue,
  * set subtract as a pendingOperation, and set the token. 
  * If no number was entered but an existing calculated
  * number is in the output display we subtract the last added
  * value from the total.
  */
  $scope.subtract = function() {
   $scope.zeroflag = false;
    if($scope.pendingValue) {
  if($scope.runningTotal && ($scope.pendingOperation == DIVIDE)) {
  $scope.runningTotal /= $scope.pendingValue;
 } else
   if($scope.runningTotal && ($scope.pendingOperation == MULTIPLY) ) {
        $scope.runningTotal *= $scope.pendingValue;
      } else
      if($scope.runningTotal && ($scope.pendingOperation == SUBTRACT) ) {
        $scope.runningTotal -= $scope.pendingValue;
      } else if($scope.runningTotal && $scope.pendingOperation == ADD ) {
        $scope.runningTotal += $scope.pendingValue;
      } else {
        $scope.runningTotal = $scope.pendingValue;
      }
    }
    setOperationToken(SUBTRACT);
    setOutput(String($scope.runningTotal));
    $scope.pendingOperation = SUBTRACT;
    $scope.newNumber = true;
    $scope.pendingValue = null;
  };
  
  
  $scope.multiply = function() {
   $scope.zeroflag = false;
    if($scope.pendingValue) {
  if($scope.runningTotal && ($scope.pendingOperation == DIVIDE)) {
  $scope.runningTotal /= $scope.pendingValue;
 } else
      if($scope.runningTotal && ($scope.pendingOperation == MULTIPLY) ) {
        $scope.runningTotal *= $scope.pendingValue;
      } else
   if($scope.runningTotal && ($scope.pendingOperation == SUBTRACT) ) {
        $scope.runningTotal -= $scope.pendingValue;
      } else if($scope.runningTotal && $scope.pendingOperation == ADD ) {
        $scope.runningTotal += $scope.pendingValue;
      } else {
        $scope.runningTotal = $scope.pendingValue;
      }
    }
    setOperationToken(MULTIPLY);
    setOutput(String($scope.runningTotal));
    $scope.pendingOperation = MULTIPLY;
    $scope.newNumber = true;
    $scope.pendingValue = null;
  };
  
   $scope.divide = function() {
    $scope.zeroflag = false;
    if($scope.pendingValue) {
  if($scope.runningTotal && ($scope.pendingOperation == DIVIDE)) {
  $scope.runningTotal /= $scope.pendingValue;
 } else
      if($scope.runningTotal && ($scope.pendingOperation == MULTIPLY) ) {
        $scope.runningTotal *= $scope.pendingValue;
      } else
   if($scope.runningTotal && ($scope.pendingOperation == SUBTRACT) ) {
        $scope.runningTotal -= $scope.pendingValue;
      } else if($scope.runningTotal && $scope.pendingOperation == ADD ) {
        $scope.runningTotal += $scope.pendingValue;
      } else {
        $scope.runningTotal = $scope.pendingValue;
      }
    }
    setOperationToken(DIVIDE);
    setOutput(String($scope.runningTotal));
    $scope.pendingOperation = DIVIDE;
    $scope.newNumber = true;
    $scope.pendingValue = null;
  };
  
  $scope.root = function() {
   $scope.zeroflag = false;
   $scope.runningTotal = Math.sqrt($scope.pendingValue);
   setOutput(String($scope.runningTotal));
   $scope.newNumber = true;
   $scope.pendingValue = null;  
  }
  
  $scope.percent = function() {
   $scope.runningTotal = $scope.runningTotal * 100;
   setOutput(String($scope.runningTotal));
   $scope.newNumber = true;
   $scope.pendingValue = null;  
  }  
  
   $scope.calculate = function() {
    $scope.zeroflag = false;
    if(!$scope.newNumber) {
      $scope.pendingValue = toNumber($scope.output);
      $scope.lastValue = $scope.pendingValue;
    }
 if($scope.pendingOperation == DIVIDE) {
  $scope.runningTotal /= $scope.pendingValue;
  $scope.lastOperation = DIVIDE;
 }
 else if($scope.pendingOperation == MULTIPLY) {
  $scope.runningTotal *= $scope.pendingValue;
  $scope.lastOperation = MULTIPLY; 
 }
    else if($scope.pendingOperation == ADD) {
      $scope.runningTotal += $scope.pendingValue;
      $scope.lastOperation = ADD;
    } else if($scope.pendingOperation == SUBTRACT) {
      $scope.runningTotal -= $scope.pendingValue;
      $scope.lastOperation = SUBTRACT;
    } else {
      if($scope.lastOperation) {
  if($scope.lastOperation == DIVIDE) {
          if($scope.runningTotal) {
            $scope.runningTotal /= $scope.lastValue;
          } else {
            $scope.runningTotal = 0;
          }
        }
  else if($scope.lastOperation == MULTIPLY) {
          if($scope.runningTotal) {
            $scope.runningTotal *= $scope.lastValue;
          } else {
            $scope.runningTotal = 0;
          }
        }  
        else if($scope.lastOperation == ADD) {
          if($scope.runningTotal) {
            $scope.runningTotal += $scope.lastValue;
          } else {
            $scope.runningTotal = 0;
          }
        } else if($scope.lastOperation == SUBTRACT) {
          if($scope.runningTotal) {
            $scope.runningTotal -= $scope.lastValue;
          } else {
            $scope.runningTotal = 0;
          }
        }
      } else {
        $scope.runningTotal = 0;
      }
    }
    setOutput($scope.runningTotal);
    setOperationToken();
    $scope.pendingOperation = null;
    $scope.pendingValue = null;
  };
})
```

```css
.content { margin-top:54px; }
.calc-body { margin:0 auto; margin-top:50px; padding:20px; border:1px solid #ccc; width:317px; background:#f9f9f9; box-shadow:0px 0px 20px #ccc;  }
.calc-screen { width:100%; height:60px; border:1px solid #ccc; margin-bottom:20px; background:#e4feef; padding:5px; }
.calc-btn-row { margin:10px 0; }
.calc-btn-row:last-child { margin-bottom:0px; }
.calc-btn-row .btn { width:60px; height:50px; margin-right:7px; cursor:pointer; text-align:center; padding:5px; }
.calc-btn-row .btn:last-child { margin-right:0px; }
.calc-history { text-align:right; }
.calc-output { text-align:right; font-size:18px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
<div class="container-fluid">
 
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
         <div class="calc-body" ng-app="calc" ng-controller="calcCtrl">
             <div class="calc-screen">
                 <div class="calc-history">{{history}}</div>
                 <div class="calc-output">{{output}}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="calc-btn-row"> 
                     <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="ac()">AC</button>
                     <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="clear()">C</button>
                     <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="divide()">&divide;</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="multiply()">&times;</button>                         
                 </div>
                
                
                <div class="calc-btn-row">
                 <button class="btn btn-secondary" ng-click="updateOutput(7)">7</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" ng-click="updateOutput(8)">8</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" ng-click="updateOutput(9)">9</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="subtract()">&minus;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="calc-btn-row">
                 <button class="btn btn-secondary" ng-click="updateOutput(4)">4</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" ng-click="updateOutput(5)">5</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" ng-click="updateOutput(6)">6</button>
                 <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="add()">&plus;</button>
                </div>
                
                <div class="calc-btn-row">
                 <button class="btn btn-secondary" ng-click="updateOutput(1)">1</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" ng-click="updateOutput(2)">2</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" ng-click="updateOutput(3)">3</button>
                 <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="root()">&radic;</button>
                </div>
                
                <div class="calc-btn-row">
                 <button class="btn btn-secondary" ng-click="updateOutput(0)">0</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-disabled="zeroflag" ng-click="updateOutput('.')">.</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="calculate()">=</button>
                 <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="percent()">%</button>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- End of calc body -->
        </div> <!-- ENd of col sm 12 -->
     </div> <!-- End of row -->   
</div> <!-- ENd of container fluid -->
</div>
```

Comment: Which 2 dots???

Comment: When i click . in calculator. the decimal points I mean to say

Comment: I mean the decimal points. try clicking on "." button twice which is not a valid operation.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i checked the calculator you put up in codepen. The dots issue mentioned by you is not occuring. Is there any specific way you are reproducing it ?

Comment: Try it initially click on "." button twice

Comment: When adding the operators + - / ÷ in any operation check wether they have already been added and if yes then don't add them.

Comment: I know that but how to code? And i asked for . not + - / x